# Oracle SQL error with concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with code that be printed in the learning book.

```
REM Describe my tables
CLEAR SCREEN
-- Create a file that is, int turn, executed
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SPOOL D:\1.sql
SELECT 'DESCRIBE' || table_name || ';'
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
ORDER BY 1;
SPOOL OFF
PROMPT
@@D:\1.sql
HOST del D:\1.sql
SET FEEDBACK ON
```

When I try to run it I see many error messages, because the "Describe" operator runs that:`"DESCRIBE<name table>` without "_". Please help me find my mistakes.

Comment: The example 
REM Describe my tables
CLEAR SCREEN
-- Create a file that is, int turn, executed
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SPOOL D:\1.sql
DESCRIBE (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
ORDER BY 1);
SPOOL OFF
PROMPT
@@D:\1.sql
HOST del D:\1.sql
SET FEEDBACK ON      also does not help.

Comment: You should give a proper title to your question. I have edited it to make it more meaningful. Please see [**How to ask a good question**](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have a **space** between the **DESCRIBE** keyword and the **TABLE** names.

**Your query:**

```
SQL> SELECT 'DESCRIBE' || table_name || ';'
  2  FROM user_tables
  3  WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
  4  ORDER BY 1;

'DESCRIBE'||TABLE_NAME||';'
-------------------------------------------
DESCRIBEDEPT;
DESCRIBEEMP;
```

You see the above output, DESCRIBE and TABLE names are not separated by space.

**Modified query:**

```
SELECT 'DESCRIBE ' || table_name || ';'
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
ORDER BY 1;
```

I have added a space after `DESCRIBE` keyword.